# Как загружать картинки в Django CKEditor

Tags: python, django, ckeditor

Всем привет! В интернете решения не нашел.

В форме благодаря CKEditor есть кнопка для загрузки изображения
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После нажатия на нее открывается окно, в котором нет возможности добавить картинку с компьютера
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: как добавить возможность добавлять картинки в форму с компьютера?

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_content = RichTextUploadingField(max_length=450000, verbose_name='Содержание', default='test')
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = []
 
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/'
CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = "/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/"
```

При необходимости могу скинуть весь код

P.S: ссылка на CKEditor https://django-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

UPD: Мне удалось добавить эту возможность, но только для админки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На странице сайта все по прежнему
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

forms.py:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    post_content = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget())
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['cat'].empty_label = 'категория не выбрана'

    captcha = CaptchaField()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['post_title', 'post_content']

    def clean_post_title(self):
        post_title = self.cleaned_data['post_title']
        if len(post_title) >= 250:
            raise ValidationError('Длина превышает 250 символов')

        return post_title
```

Вопрос: как это пофиксить?

Comment: на сколько я понял, в базе нет такой поддержки, потому что нет файлового браузера. надо подключать плагины. подробнее [тут](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/images/images-overview.html)

Comment: Dmitry Nekrasov, спасибо за отклик! Я дополнил вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение было простое.
В forms.py просто удалить или закомментировать строку

`post_content = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget())`